# Namehiding and overriding - Is there a way to make a function explicitly not overriding

Tags: c++, c++20, name-hiding

I would like to hide a virtual method instead of override. I know for historic / compatibility reasons the override specifier is optional and overriding happens implicitly.
To stop overriding I usually adjusted the signature by adding a defaulted "Dummy" parameter. Is there a better way?

Assume this code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
public:
    virtual void Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "A::Foo";
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void Foo() /*not override, just hide*/
    {
        std::cout << "B::Foo";
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b{};
    A& a = b;
    a.Foo(); //should print A::Foo - but prints B::Foo
}
```

What I did so far is this:

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
public:
    virtual void Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "A::Foo";
    }
};

template<typename T>
class reintroduce{};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void Foo(reintroduce<B> = {}) /*not override, just hide*/
    {
        std::cout << "B::Foo";
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b{};
    A& a = b;
    a.Foo(); //should print A::Foo
}
```

Comment: Nope, C++ does not work this way.

Comment: I know - it's because in the past there was no override specifier...
But do you have any recommendations / ideas to get the desired behaviour? It works with the "dummy type" - but it's not really nice. Perhaps it is the best way to go, but...

Comment: In your first example, why not just don't implement `B::Foo()` and it'll call `A::Foo()`? [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9Tc4f6)

Comment: Hiding a virtual method goes against Liskov's substitution principle. Why do you wish to do it?

Comment: The introduction of the override specifier makes absolutely no difference, whatsoever. C++ still did not work this way before this keyword, too. My recommendation would be to explain what real problem you need to solve. No, not the one about not overriding virtual functions. But the one where you believe not overriding virtual functions is the solution, so that's what you're asking about.

Comment: I write a compiler - the original code is written in another language which supports hiding of virtual methods... Or requires an explicit override.
This is just a simple sample code.
You are right - such code is bad. But I need to translate it.

Comment: `is written in another language` Why not specify it? In which language? How does the language support "hiding virtual methods"?

Comment: It is CSharp - in csharp exists a new modifier to explicitly hide a function (which is optional). To override some function you need to use the override keyword. Without this keyword such function is just hiding it's base function (not by name - by signature but that is another topic).

For more info: see here https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/classes.md#methods

Answer (score 0):

The question is not too clear on the requirements of "*hiding*" but the following effectively "*hides*" the inherited method in the derived class, while not changing its visibility/accessibility in the base class.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    virtual void Foo()
    {   std::cout << "A::Foo"; }
};

class B : public A
{
private:
    using A::Foo;
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.Foo();     // error, cannot access private member
    b.A::Foo();  // ok, calls A::Foo

    A& a = b;
    a.Foo();     // ok, calls A::Foo
}
```